# Syntax to define a new control-flow construct in R?

Tags: r

How can a new [control-flow construct](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html) be defined in R?

#### Background

An object can be defined like so

```r
obj <- "some_string"
obj <- 5
```

A function can be defined like so

```r
my_funct <- function(x) {
  x * 2
}
```

#### Question

What is the syntax to define a new control-flow construct?

#### Example of what I'm after

This could create a new control-flow construct called `until`

```r
until <- control {
  # some code here to make 'until' accept a condition (e.g. `x == 5` 
  # and execute { break } if condition met
}
```

Which could be used like so

```r
x <- 1 

until (x == 3) {
  print(x)
  x <- x + 1
}
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
```

#### Notes

- Existing control-flow constructs in R include `for`, `if`, `while`, and `break`.
- More info at `?Control`

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is feasible or possible to create new control-flow constructs in runtime in R. The constructs you quote (`for`, `if`, `while`, `break`, and `next`) are defined by the language, and implemented in the base code of R because the parse needs to know how to handle it. An analogy would be to "oh, the Oxford grammar rule -- that's cool (look up the [strippers Stalin and Hitler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhIxX.jpg), link kinda SFW); I'm gonna start using that rule in French." You would have to describe and explain how the rule/construct is applied to the context.

Your example, `until`, is the same as `while`. I.e.

```
while (x == 3) {
  print(x)
  x <- x + 1
}
```

Put another way, what is it you need or are missing, since you are looking to implement a new control-flow construct?

There is additionally the operators, `+`, `-`, `%in%`, ..., that you *can* implement. These operators are no more than functions (albeit the algebraic are primitives) that take 2 arguments. These functions use the method dispatch system, so you can achieve nuanced behaviours depending on what you are adding.